# Unable to install python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, installation

I follow this [tut](http://www.howtogeek.com/197947/how-to-install-python-on-windows/) to install python on Windows 7 (64 bit).
But I get an error: 0x80070643: *Failed to Install MSI Package*: [image]
What's wrong? 
P. S. The 1st and 3d methods of [this guide](http://www.techpayee.com/failed-to-install-msi-package) have not worked for me.

### Update

Should I tick up *Add Python to PATH* box? 
[image]

### Update 2

I've doanloaded the *x86-64 embeddable zip file*, unzipped it into Python35 and now it works.

Comment: Looks like the 32-bits version of Python. Did you tried with 64-bits ?

Comment: Did you run the installer as admin?

Comment: @stendarr, I did run installer as admin.

Comment: @CalEliacheff, upon your suggestion I've deliberately chosen 64-bits version: http://joxi.net/vAWYEDwuoMK7mW but no avail...

Comment: According to the screen capture in your last comment, you are trying to install Python 3.6.0. That version of Python is not yet finished--it is still in beta, as shown by the b in the file name. Beta versions still have problems. Try the current complete version, 3.5.2, instead. Get 3.6.0 when it is completed, probably in December.

Comment: @RoryDaulton, You are right, please see my *Update 2*.

Comment: The embedded distribution is neither a proper development nor system version of Python. You need to install the regular 64-bit version of Python 3.5.2.  If you're installing for all users, it should have elevated to admin access, and if an admin can't create a subkey at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer`, then the security on the key is broken. Fix it.

Comment: @eryksun, how can I *fix the security on the key* ?

Comment: Use regedit to check the permissions on the key. `Administrators` should have full control.

Comment: @eryksun, I've checked the permission of the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer` key (for Administrators): http://joxi.net/v29JbQKcPox8AG - they are set to allow both  read and full-control.

Comment: That tells us that the installer -- at least for screenshot case you've shown -- either didn't run as an admin or that the registry key has a deny ACE in its security descriptor. The former is more likely. Do you get the same error about not being able to create the registry key when running the web installer for the 64-bit version of 3.5.2?

Comment: Do not post solutions in the Question. Write an Answer, or delete the question.

Answer (score 4):

Close the installation program and follow:

1. On the desktop, press <kbd>Windows key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open a Run dialog.
2. Type `msiexec /unreg`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Follow the first step again.
4. Type `msiexec /regserver`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

In this [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/unable-to-install-msi-packages-error-there-is-a/52695c2b-87b8-4909-8874-7d66eeb1a8f6?auth=1) you can find more information.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Task Manager -> Details Tab -> End Task 'msiexec.exe'
- Try install again.

[image]